# Bose Revolve Soundlink USB output no sound

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio

I am trying to get my Bose Revolve Soundlink to work trough USB (Bluetooth and AUX works fine). Using it trough USB on Windows works fine too.

The speakers get detected just fine, but when I change to the correct output device there is no sound.

I have two output profiles to change between in `pavucontrol`: "Analog Stero" and "Digital Stero (IEC958)". none of them work.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 67
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xf7700000 irq 69
 2 [SoundLink      ]: USB-Audio - Bose Revolve SoundLink
                      Bose Corporation Bose Revolve SoundLink at usb-0000:02:00.0-10, full speed
```

from dmesg:

```
[ 5287.800381] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 5288.137063] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=05a7, idProduct=40fa
[ 5288.137067] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5288.137069] usb 1-10: Product: Bose Revolve SoundLink
[ 5288.137072] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: Bose Corporation
[ 5288.137074] usb 1-10: SerialNumber: Q73160860107429561A0210
[ 5288.197492] input: Bose Corporation Bose Revolve SoundLink as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.2/0003:05A7:40FA.0009/input/input36
```

from `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05a7:40fa Bose Corp. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x05a7 Bose Corp.
  idProduct          0x40fa 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          156
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          1 Audio
      bFunctionSubClass       1 Control Device
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength           43
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        bControlSize            2
        bmaControls( 0)      0x03
        bmaControls( 0)      0x00
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
        bmaControls( 1)      0x00
        bmaControls( 1)      0x00
        bmaControls( 2)      0x00
        bmaControls( 2)      0x00
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0301 Speaker
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               2
        iTerminal               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           1
        bDelay                  0 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                14
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            2 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        48000
        tSamFreq[ 1]        44100
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x81
            Sampling Frequency
            MaxPacketsOnly
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00c0  1x 192 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     126
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

I have tried rebooting.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, I solved my own problem.

edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and add:

```
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

The important part here is to set the sample rate to 48000 I believe.

Another strange note: With analog profile selected, it works only if the audio is **EXACTLY** 100%. and a nice way to do testing is running the command `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav`

Comment: I had the same problem and your suggestion fixed the problem in the same way: The sound output works as long as the volume (in pulseaudio) is set to 100%.   If you use `alsamixer` you can set the volume to anything else, too, as long as you have selected the Soundlink as audio chip (F6).   However, I got it to work with the `pulseaudio` volume control by updating `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common` in and setting `volume = ignore` in the `Element PCM` section.    That way the volume levels _should_ be synchronized across pulseaudio and the soundlink in alsa.

Comment: Editing `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` how you described worked for me after I restarted the pulseaudio daemon using `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service` and `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.socket`